RSA ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey on Windows Server 2019 doesn't work
I have an API in .NET 6 for validating that .cer and .Key files are correlated and validating that the password corresponds to the .KEY. The code I am using is:
public static bool ValidateCertificateKey(string certPath, string keyPath, string keyPassword)
{
    try
    {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certPath);

        using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(keyPath);
            RSAParameters rsaParams = ConvertToRSAParameters(keyBytes, keyPassword);
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParams);

            byte[] message = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            byte[] signature = rsa.SignData(message, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

            RSA publicKey = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();

            bool verificationCorrect = publicKey.VerifyData(message, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

            return verificationCorrect;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}

static RSAParameters ConvertToRSAParameters(byte[] keyBytes, string password)
{
    using (var rsa = RSA.Create())
    {
        rsa.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(password, keyBytes, out _);
        return rsa.ExportParameters(true);
    }
}

Is there something I am missing?
In my development environment with Visual Studio 2022, it works correctly, but in production under IIS, I get an error "The EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo structure was decoded but was not successfully interpreted, the password may be incorrect." on the line rsa.ImportEncryptedPkcs8PrivateKey(password, keyBytes, out _); even though it is the correct password.
Has anyone experienced this situation? Even in my desperation, I installed Visual Studio on the server, and in the environment with Visual Studio's IISExpress, it worked as it does in my local environment.

Are you sure it's PKCS8 with BER/CER/DER encoding (not PEM), and that the password is correct? Anyway why are you not using the certificate store to store the RSA key?
